# Is a way to curry multiple ramda's assocPath methods in a redux reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ramda.js

So wanted to know if there is any way I could curry multiple assocPath methods in redux reducer. What I wish to do is update the state of an object and array in my redux reducer without mutating it. For which I have to set a value in multiple object/ arrays. The way I am trying to do it is via creating a clone of the object and updating it and then again set it to the state, this I am doing in my components state.
So currently I am do something like this in my components state. I wish to do the similar in the redux reducer

```
 let newState;
    newState = _.assocPath(["project", "value"], project, this.state);
    newState = _.assocPath(["project", "error"], false, newState);
    this.setState(newState);
```

But the problem is in redux reducer I ma not able to do it. I have to curry the methods one after the other.

Please let me know if you want more info.
Thank you

Comment: Please include the code you are using now, and try to explain the problem with examples.

Comment: Thank you @OriDrori for replying, I have added a code snippet please let me know if it is still not clear

Answer (score 2):

I would create the reducer using R.mergeDeepLeft with the object that I wish to merge with the original state, and then call it on the old state.

**Example**:

```js
const state = { project: { value: null, error: true, other: 'other' } }
const project = {}

const reducer = R.mergeDeepLeft({
  project: {
    value: project,
    error: false
  }
})

const newState = reducer(state)

console.log(newState)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution from Ori Drori is better than this, but this seems to me to be what you're asking for:

```js
const foo = (project, errVal) => pipe (
  prop ('state'),
  assocPath (["project", "value"], project),
  assocPath (["project", "error"], errVal)
) 

this .setState (foo (project, false) (this))
```

`foo` (ok, so I'm terrible at naming!) accepts your `project` and `err` values and returns a function which accepts an object and returns an updated version of its `state` property, after setting `project.value` and `project.error`.  Is this what you're looking to do?

### Terminology

You say this:

> But the problem is in redux reducer I am not able to do it. I have to curry the methods one after the other.

And I just want to point out some problems with the wording.  First, Ramda does not have *methods*.  Methods are functions that act on an object's state.  Ramda is very careful to not mutate your state at all.  Ramda instead simply has *functions*.  `R` (or `_` if you choose) serves as a namespace for a large number of independent functions.

And second, what you're doing has nothing to do with *currying*.  You're simply *calling* the functions.  My answer uses `pipe` to compose some functions into a new one, and perhaps that's what you meant.  Currying is the process of converting a function of multiple arguments into a nested sequence of single-argument functions.  `(a, b, c) => 'foo'  ===> (a) => (b) => (c) => 'foo'`.  Ramda's currying has some additional features that let you call the resulting function in more ways, but the point is that nothing in the question has anything to do with currying.